# Не срабатывает foreach

Tags: c#

Хочу отфильтровать и сгруппировать по описанию, однако foreach пропускается и ничего не выводится на экран. Однако если я фильтрую по температуре, то все работает, в чем проблема, почему он не работает?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<WeatherInfo> lweatherInfo = new List<WeatherInfo>();
 var selectedUsers = from user in lweatherInfo
                                where user.description ==  "Дождь"//
                                group user by user.description into g
                                select new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
            foreach (var group in selectedUsers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{group.Name} : {group.Count}");//$"{user.description} - {user.temperature}");
            }
        }
```

Comment: А в описаниях точно есть "Дождь"? Именно так с большой буквы?

Comment: @CrazyElf Да именно так все и есть

Comment: Ну я бы всё-таки попробовал убрать where и посмотрел что в group.Name попадает, там всё что угодно может быть - лишний пробел, например

Comment: @CrazyElf а можно еще вопрос, каким образом можно найти максимальное значение через запрос linq

Comment: Ну там max должен быть, но в sql-образном синтаксисе я не умею, а через точку там просто .Max() был

Comment: Не знаю как в sql стиле, но вот так должен адекватно отработать если в дескрипшене есть слово дождь. var selectedUsers = lweatherInfo.Where(x => x.description == "Дождь").GroupBy(x => x.description).Select(x => new {Name = x.Key, Count = x.Count()});